# О грамматической основе предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Что является грамматической основой предложения?

«Мы были в зале ресторана.»

Answer (score 1):

> *Мы были в зале ресторана.*
>
> Что является грамматической основой предложения?

***Мы были.***

***Мы***  — подлежащее, ***были*** (= присутствовали, находились...) —  сказуемое.

Answer (score 0):

Грамматическая основа: мы были (находились), простое глагольное сказуемое.

Для сравнения: Письмо было от брата. Квартира была без мебели. Мы были в восторге. Это составное именное сказуемое, именная часть выражена предложно-падежным оборотом.